# How to create frame/tables around multiple plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, frame, box, par

[image]

I've tried many ways **to create box/frame or tables around multiple plots** to group them but I came up either a way to create a box for only one plot or a frame for an entire list of plots.

I made some statistical analysis in R and ended up with many plots/graphics (i.e hists, qq plots, residuals). To organize them I don't want to draw tables for hundreds of the plots in Word or Excell. Instead, I wonder if there is a way to create such tables/frame in R rather than doing manually.

Comment: Have you tried `?box` and specifically the argument `which`?

Comment: Also, take a look at `layout`, particularly if you used base plots.

Comment: @csgroen I created tables by using layout function even though I wasn’t sure how the layout function divides the windows splits. However, I figured out later. (layout.show)

Comment: @AdamO I didn’t yet. Not sure how to do this actually.